# How to use join of dplyr in r?

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I need help regarding this database https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer
I need a table of the date , the hometeam name and the goals the hometeam scored , for a random game  ( I chose Match.match_api_id = 492476). I want to get this table in two ways: by an SQL statement and by r using the dplyr package. The SQL statement is the following :

```
SELECT Match.date ,Team.team_long_name ,Match.home_team_goal
FROM Team JOIN Match
ON Match.home_team_api_id = Team.team_api_id
WHERE Match.match_api_id = 492476;
```

I am struggling with dplyr though.
Question: In order to use join in r , to join two lazy querys , they must both have a column with the same name, so the join is done by that column? And also should one of theese two columns be the foreign key of this query and correspond to the column of the other query with the same name?

I run this code

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "data/database.sqlite")
country<-tbl(con,"Country")
league<-tbl(con,"League")
match<-tbl(con,"Match")
team<-tbl(con,"Team")
team_attributes<-tbl(con,"Team_Attributes")
player_attributes<-tbl(con,"Player_Attributes")
player<-tbl(con,"Player")

table_1<-match %>%
  filter(match_api_id=492476) %>%
  select(date,home_team_goal,home_team_api_id) %>%
  left_join(team)
```

and get this error

! `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

- Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I think the error's suggestion is clear: you need to either specify `by=` explicitly or ensure that there are common field names (even in the latter case, I still recommend being explicit about `by` columns). Try `.. %>% left_join(team, by=c(home_team_api_id = "team_api_id"))`.

Comment: Why the [tag:mysql] tag? It sounds like you're replicating a SQL query and want to translate into `dplyr::*_join`, yet you use SQLite to demo it. Frankly, since you are not asking for help with the SQL itself, I think the actual DBMS is a moot point here.